# Send ruby post with nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, http-post

I have following nested hash:

```
$installation_settings = {
  :lat => "43.107044",
  :lon => "25.194757",
  :country => "Poland",
  :collector_installation => {
      :people => 3,
      :deviation_from_s => 5,
      :solar_collector_id => 1,
      :collectors_number => 2,
      :monthly_water_consumption => 6000,
      :gas_price => 0.09, 
      :electricity_price => 0.87            
  }
}
```

which I'm trying to send through post with ruby:

```
url = "someURL"
uri = URI(url)
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, $installation_settings)
puts res.body
```

Net::HTTP.post_form only enables sending simple Hashes (without nesting), so I end up getting string with backslashes.

How should I send it?

Comment: Usually this data is being sent as json, but there is no sufficient information to suggest a proper way in this particular case.

Comment: I find for simple things like this [`HTTParty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem does a fantastic job.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form) say that the hash must be in `string: string` format.  So a nested hash would look like:

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI('http://localhost'), 'a': { 'b': '2' })
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it mentions `string: string` format ? For me it says it should be a Hash mapping from String to String. `'a': { 'b': '2' }` isn't a valid Hash in Ruby, I think it should instead be : `'a' => { 'b' => '2' }`.

Comment: In Ruby 2.2.2 `{ 'a': '2' }` is a valid hash.  Hash rockets are no longer necessary for stringed keys.

Comment: Ah you are right, too bad I didn't keep track of the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with an older version with Ruby so unfortunately I could not apply Anthony's answer. However, I found another solution which might help someone:

```
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = false  
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.body = installation_hash.to_json
response = http.request(request)
```